# Adobe AIR: how to play and download an audio file synchronously?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3, adobe, air

in adobe air , I can play a mp3 file from the web , and download the file to a custom file system before or after too . but in this way  I have to download the file twice factly.

So, how to save the file to a custom location when the sound is playing , and using the same download file stream for not waste any bits?